# Scala, Hammock - retrieve http response headers and convert JSON to custom object

Tags: scala, scala-cats, hammock

I have created a simple program which use `Hammock`(https://github.com/pepegar/hammock) and now I would like to get response from `github` API with reposne's headers. I created a code like this:

```
object GitHttpClient extends App {
  implicit val decoder = jsonOf[IO, List[GitRepository]]
  implicit val interpreter = ApacheInterpreter.instance[IO]

  val response = Hammock
    .request(Method.GET, uri"https://api.github.com/orgs/github/repos?per_page=3", Map())
    .as[List[GitRepository]]
    .exec[IO]
    .unsafeRunSync()

  println(response)
}

case class GitRepository(full_name: String, contributors_url: String)
```

And it works fine, I got `Git` data mapped to my object. But now I also want to get `headers` from `response` and I cannot do this by simple `response.headers`. Only when I remove `.as[List[GitRepository]]` line and have whole `HttpResponse` I could access `headers`. Is it possible to get `headers` without parsing whole `HttpResponse`?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using `Decoder` after received reponse:

```
 val response = Hammock
    .request(Method.GET, uri"https://api.github.com/orgs/github/repos?per_page=3", Map())
    .exec[IO]
    .unsafeRunSync()

    println(response.headers("Link") contains ("next"))
    println(HammockDecoder[List[GitRepository]].decode(response.entity))
```